# Is NHibernate.Spatial compatible with NHibernate 3.0?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, gis, orm, spatial

I want to use NHibernate.Spatial. I also want to use new NHibernate 3.0 features such as the improved LINQ provider and the QueryOver functionality, which are only available in NHibernate's source control trunk.

Are these two things compatible? I can't work without Spatial but I really want the LINQ features, which will have to go if they can't be used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a week of tinkering, I can answer that yes, this is possible. I am now using the following trunks together:

- NHibernate
- Fluent
- Castle Windsor
- NHibernate.Spatial
- MVCContrib (the IoC container helper)

I tried building them myself, which was painful. Now I'm simply using the hornget versions, which are all built against the latest trunk.

Comment: This might be a long shot but do you know the link to NHibernate.Spatial on hornget, I had a look but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Hornget is no longer available. You have to build from source.